# Set proof for intro to pure math class: $(A-C)\subseteq (A-B)\cup (B-C)$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I don't know if this question has been asked but I couldn't find it. The question is: Suppose $A,B,C$ are sets. Prove that $(A-C)\subseteq (A-B)\cup (B-C)$.

What I have is: Let $x\in (A-B)\cup (B-C)$ then $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$ or $x\in B$ and $x\notin C$. Hence, $x\in (A-C)\implies (A-C)\subseteq (A-B)\cup (B-C)$.

Now my question is, is it acceptable to work from the right to the left as I have just done. My conclusion follows intuition; however, it seems a bit *unformal* to me. Thanks!

---

**EDIT**

For my second attempt, I broke the problem into two, when $x\in B$ and $x\notin B$.

Let $x\in (A-C)$ then $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$. Now, if $x\in B$ then, $x\notin (A-B)$ but $x\in (B-C)$. So, $x\in (A-B)\cup (B-C)$. If $x\notin B$, then $x\in (A-B)$ and $x\notin (B-C)$. So, $x\in (A-B)\cup (B-C)$.

Is my proof valid now?

Comment: No, you need to choose an $x$ from the left and prove that it is an element in the right.

Comment: Generally, when you show one set is a subset of another set, you need to start with the supposed smaller set and show that every element of it is also an element of the larger set.

Comment: `Hence ...` What follows doesn't really *prove* anything, just states it.

Comment: Thank you, I will work and try to solve it again

Comment: @TonyMau Yes, the proof under the edit looks correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $x\in (A-C)$ then $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$. Now, if $x\in B$ then, $x\notin (A-B)$ but $x\in (B-C)$. So, $x\in (A-B)\cup (B-C)$. If $x\notin B$, then $x\in (A-B)$ and $x\notin (B-C)$. So, $x\in (A-B)\cup (B-C)$.

Yes, that is the form for a proof by cases, and the reasoning in each branch is valid.  It may need some polish, but that's the shape of it.

For instance, you need to complete it. "Then in either case any $x\in A\smallsetminus C$ infers that $x\in(A\smallsetminus B)\cup (B\smallsetminus C)$, so therefore $A\smallsetminus C \subseteq (A\smallsetminus B)\cup (B\smallsetminus C)$." or such.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

Your proof does not imply $$(A-C)\subseteq (A-B)\cup (B-C)$$

Note that

If $x$ is in $A-C$ the $x$ is in $A$ and $x$ is not in $C.$

There are two cases regarding $x$ and $B.$

If $x$ is in $B$ it is in $B-C$

If $x$ is  not in $B$, then it is in $A-B$

In either case $x$ is in the union $ (A-B)\cup (B-C)$

That is $$(A-C)\subseteq (A-B)\cup (B-C)$$

Comment: Thank you for the clear response, I addressed this in my edit

Comment: Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

When you union $(A-B)$ with $(B-C)$ you are "putting back" into $A$ all the elements in $B$ that you took away **except** for those that are in $C$.  $A$ less **all** the elements in $C$ must be equal to or a subset of this.